# Difference between MultiplicativeLR and LambdaLR

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Can someone explain difference between torch.optim.lr_scheduler.LambdaLR(https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html) and torch.optim.lr_scheduler.MultiplicativeLR(https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html)?

Here is brief description of MultiplicativeLR:

[image]

and LambdaLR [image]

Comment: @NazarKhan I suggest you post that as an answer.

Comment: I tend to start from the comments as this is an educated guess and not necessarily correct. Please wait until I cross-check this information. These two functions are so similar that there was even an issue posted on PyTorch as LambdaLR was used as an example for MultiplicativeLR

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main difference is that they use a different function for computing the learning rate of the function.

`LambdaLR`'s function is:

[image]

While `MultiplicativeLR`'s function is:

[image]

Thus they would have a different result for the learning rate. Both are useful for a variety of scenarios.